# Images not displaying after ajax function until workspace refresh

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, eclipse

**Background:** I just finished a registration form for my site on my local host. Within the form users upload their first profile picture. The form is submitted with ajax, validated on the server side, and the image is written on the server side to a folder. Once the image is written I return that users username to the ajax success and then they are redirected to their newly created homepage.

**Problem:** When I test the form out on my local host all their data is imported into the db as expected. However the files are written to a folder within my eclipse workspace and it is not noticing the new data. I've tweaked my eclipse workspace preferences but it's refusing to refresh when the new images hit the files. So unfortunately, when the user is redirected to their homepage they are shown a 404 where their image should be. It will stay like this until I go into eclipse and refresh my workspace and then it shows up. I've figured out that the images are completely written to the file before the ajax success is called so the function isn't going too fast, the server (or eclipse workspace) is not refreshing.

**Question:** Is this something I should worry about when I transfer my site to a godaddy VPS? I am concerned that when users upload images the same thing will happen and they'll have to wait for however long it takes the server to realize there is new content. And this could be devastating to site popularity if I am displaying 404 images to users who are having their first experirience with the site. So Is there something I should do to prevent this problem on my local host. But more importantly do you think this will happen on a live server and if so what should I do?

**Code:** Here's my javascript code. So should I do anything in my success area to maybe check for this problem?

```
function addNewUser()
{
    var form = new FormData();
    var ajaxObject = getAjaxObject();
    var gender = (getElement('registerMale').checked) ? "his" : "her";
    form.append("userName", getValue('registerUserName'));
    form.append("email", getValue('registerEmail'));
    form.append("password", getValue('registerPassword'));
    form.append("fName", getValue('registerFName'));
    form.append("lName", getValue('registerLName'));
    form.append("displayName", getValue('registerFName') + " " + getValue("registerLName"));
    form.append("location", getValue('registerLocation'));
    form.append("gender", gender);
    form.append("currentDefault", getElement("registerCurrentDefault").files[0]);
    form.append("discipline", getValue("registerDiscipline"));
    form.append("birthDay", getValue("registerBirthDay"));
    form.append("birthMonth", getValue("registerBirthMonth"));
    form.append("birthYear", getValue("registerBirthYear"));

    ajaxObject.open("POST", "addNewUser", true);
    ajaxObject.send(form);

    ajaxObject.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(ajaxObject.readyState == 4 && ajaxObject.status == 200)
        {
            divLink("profile?user=" + ajaxObject.responseText);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem to worry about.
Try running the app from the application server you are using. You will get the expected result.